# How to Validate Drop-down inside GridView using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to validate a drop down inside a gridview on a button click.  If the drop down has no selection then i want to fire the javascript but the code is not firing at all.  I am not sure what am i doing wrong here so please help.  thanks.
Here is the button code in the aspx file:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="183px" Visible="true"
                onclick="btnSubmit_Click" 
                OnClientClick="return validate();" 
                Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Height="30px" 
                style="margin-right: 1px; margin-left: 185px;" ForeColor="#336699" />
```

here is the javascript in the head section of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function validate() {
              var flag = true;
              var dropdowns = new Array(); //Create array to hold all the dropdown lists.
              var gridview = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>'); //GridView1 is the id of ur gridview.
              dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('--'); //Get all dropdown lists contained in GridView1.
              for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                  if (dropdowns.item(i).value == '--') //If dropdown has no selected value
                  {
                      flag = false;
                      break; //break the loop as there is no need to check further.
                  }
              }
              if (!flag) {
                  alert('Please select value in each dropdown');
              }
              return flag;
          }
</script>
```

here is my drop-down in the aspx:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblAns" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DDL_ANS")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Answer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
  </asp:DropDownList>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

here is the code behind for the dropdown

```
 ddl_Answer.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    ddl_Answer.DataTextField = "DD_ANSWER";
                    ddl_Answer.DataValueField = "DD_ANSWER";
                    ddl_Answer.DataBind();
ddl_Answer.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you trying to select the dropdown using javascript. You probably want this

```
dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('select');
```